# Bootstrap 4 vertical align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center the content, vertical and  horizontal. I'm having some problems with the vertical part: [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G0xwY5PZM47XG7dYU57o?p=preview)

My custom css card:

```css
.customCard {
  width: 15rem; 
  height: 7rem;
  background-color: blue;
  color:#eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card-block ">
    <div class="card customCard  mt-2 customCursorPointer">
      <div class="card-body">
      <div class="container d-flex r h-100">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mx-auto align-items-center">
            <h4 class="card-title">AAAA</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `height:100%` in `.card-body`

```css
.customCard {
  width: 15rem; 
  height: 7rem;
  background-color: blue;
  color:#eee;
}
.card-body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card-block ">
    <div class="card customCard  mt-2 customCursorPointer">
      <div class="card-body">
      <div class="container d-flex r h-100">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mx-auto align-items-center">
            <h4 class="card-title">AAAA</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I just used "h-100" class insead of creating a new one.